# Get ContentType of library when any document is added in Shared Document

Tags: content-type

I have 3 content type in my Shared document.Now I want to get the content type name when any document is added in shared document programatically. I want to know when an item is added which content type is being used out of the 3 content types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code will be something like this

```
 SPContentType contentType = myListItem.ContentType;
   string contentTypeName=contentType.Name
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype_properties.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use `SPListItem.ContentType`. This will give `SPContentType`. And you can use `SPContentType.Name` to get the name of content type.